# Help Identifying a few Molex-style Connector?

Tags: connector, identification

I would like to find replacements for the connectors in the below photos. They're in an arcade game called Pump it Up (think the Korean version of Dance Dance Revolution), and connect the dance pads to the main cabinet. The cabinet was likely made in the early 2000s.

---

I'm only interested in finding the two plugs with the female pins (red in the below photos), but the mating connectors are shown below for reference. They just connect from wire to wire. I suspect they may have been made by Molex since I've found other connectors in the cabinet that I've identified and replaced with Molex-made parts, but they could've just as easily been made by anyone else.

---

Any help identifying those two red connectors would be a huge help, bonus points if you can point me towards the pins I would need to get for the connectors, too.

---

[image: 4 electronics connectors, two 15-pin and two 6-pin]

[image: A ruler held up next to the first 15 pin connector]

Comment: I tried to look around on a few manufacturer's websites (Molex, TE Connectivity, etc) and on a few sites like Mouser and Digikey and was able to find similar connectors, but they didn't look to be exactly the same (different keying/plug shapes, etc). There's a good chance I might've missed something since I'm not super experienced in doing this, but I figured if anything the people around here might be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was estimate the pin pitch uing the ruler in the photo and then do a look-up on digikey.  none of the parts had photos so I downloaded datasheets.

The 3x5 is Molex mini-fit  Molex 0015311152, Molex 0015311151

Digikey has the part in the catalogue, but no stock

https://www.digikey.co.nz/product-detail/en/molex/0015311152/0015311152-ND/3122315

If the 2x3 is the same pitch it's probably mini-fit too.
Molex 0015311063, Molex 0015311062

Crimp pins, and tool available separately.

Comment: Those do indeed look like the connectors, shame that both Digikey and Molex's sites say that those part numbers for the 3x5 connector are obsolete now. If anything the 2x3 connector is still in production (it is the same pitch as the 3x5 connector, by the way) so I might pick those up and just re-crimp the 3x5 ones with a similar connector. Mystery solved, thanks for the help!

Comment: it should be possible to extract the pins from the 3x5 and use them is a different shell. release tools are cheap.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks for the tip